# Caching images in large tableview without slowing down performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, caching, uiimageview

I currently made an app which contains a tableview with 1000 cells. Each cell contains on the left side a UIImageview in the contentview. All the image files are currently stored in the NSBundle. Unfortunately the app is to big in size to download over 3g (one of the regelations from Apple) and I will need to cache these images.

I currently am downloading and saving each image once the cell is on the view (dereusable cell) but this slows down the scrolling drastically. Is their a way to keep the scrolling fast but once the user stops at a certain position it caches those files? I tried an NSOperationQueue but this did'nt work out for me.

Some hints in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are the same downloading and displaying a table view, it's normal that you have a performance drop in the fps you get from your tableview as the cpu is using some of it's threads to download the data...

The only way you could gain in performance is if you speed up the drawing of your tableview cells by using core graphics to draw directly into the cell (as Loren Brichter demonstrated with the tweetie app).